# how to pick a random entry in excel based on percent

Tags: excel

im trying to find some way to pick a random entry from a list based on percent. id like to do this in excel but im not sure how to do it. heres an example of the list:

A - 25% | B - 50% | C - 25%

id like to be able to randomly select one of the variables based on there corresponding percent (B is chosen 50%, C is chosen 25% etc..)
how would i do this?
(the real list has about 250 variables, not sure if that changes anything)

Comment: try google **approximate match** using either VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP and come back if you have more specific questions on how to use these two formulas.

Comment: You question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works in EXCEL for you.
[image]